# Solr All checkers need to use the same Analyzer

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to run the spellcheck on some indexed data. I originally figure out how to do it but I messed with some configurations and now its saying that "All checkers need to use the same Analyzer." I've read that this is because the "field" values are named different things. I've made all the spellcheck components spell. What else do I doing wrong.

I get that error when I type is

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=name%3Adoc&wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

My solrconfig.xml

```xml
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

    <lst name="defaults">
        <!-- Optional, must match spell checker's name as defined above, defaults to "default" -->
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <!-- Also generate Word Break Suggestions (Solr 4.0 see SOLR-2993) -->
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
        <!-- omp = Only More Popular -->
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <!-- exr = Extended Results -->
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
        <!--  The number of suggestions to return -->
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>

</requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">

        <str name="name">default</str>
        <!-- The classname is optional, defaults to IndexBasedSpellChecker -->
        <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>

        <str name="field">spell</str>
        <!-- Optional, by default use in-memory index (RAMDirectory) -->
        <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
        <!-- Set the accuracy (float) to be used for the suggestions. Default is 0.5 -->
        <str name="accuracy">0.7</str>
        <!-- Require terms to occur in 1/100th of 1% of documents in order to be included in the   dictionary -->
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>
    </lst>
    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words. (Solr 4.0 see SOLR-2993) -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
        <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
        <str name="field">spell</str>
        <str name="combineWords">true</str>
        <str name="breakWords">true</str>
        <int name="maxChanges">3</int>
    </lst>
    <!-- Example of using different distance measure -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">jarowinkler</str>
        <str name="field">spell</str>
        <!--  Use a different Distance Measure -->
        <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>
        <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
    </lst>

    <!-- This field type's analyzer is used by the QueryConverter to tokenize the value for "q" parameter -->
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
</searchComponent>


<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">spell</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>

        <str name="field">suggest</str>
        <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

    </lst>

</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>

    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

My schema.xml

```xml
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="sku" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="manu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="features" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="includes" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />

<field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

StackTrace

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All checkers need to use the 
    same Analyzer.\n\tat org.apache.solr.spelling.ConjunctionSolrSpellChecker.addChecker(
    ConjunctionSolrSpellChecker.java:79)\n\tat org.apache.
    solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.getSpellChecker(SpellCheckComponent.java:501)
    \n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.prepare(SpellCheckComponent.
    java:122)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody
    (SearchHandler.java:187)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest
    (RequestHandlerBase.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute
    (SolrCore.java:1904)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:659)
    \n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter
    (SolrDispatchFilter.java:362)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter
    (SolrDispatchFilter.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
    (ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
    (ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
    (StandardWrapperValve.java:222)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
    (StandardContextValve.java:123)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
    (StandardHostValve.java:171)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
    (ErrorReportValve.java:99)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke
    (AccessLogValve.java:953)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
    (StandardEngineValve.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
    (CoyoteAdapter.java:408)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    \n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
    (AbstractProtocol.java:589)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    \n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    \n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)\n",
        "code":500}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found out the reason that I was getting this error was that I was calling it spell. When I changed that spell to name it worked. I guess spell was being used which makes sense.

Comment: I also have this problem. Could you be more precise, what exactly solved your problem? At what point did you rename spell to name?

Comment: Can you explain in detail, I'm also getting same issue over Solr Instance with Arabic language.

Answer (score 11):

The Error indicates the same field should be used by all the Spell Checkers defined.
In your Configuration you are using different fields (`spell` & `suggest`) for different checker.

`<str name="field">spell</str>` AND `<str name="field">suggest</str>`

Comment: @JaspreetChauhan Can you please tell me how you fixed it. I am facing same problem.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by setting each spellchecker's buildOnCommit member to true in addition to using the same field.

Answer (score 2):

All fields, that are used in the spellchecker components (in the example spell and suggest), must use the same **analysis chain**. Analysis chain means they have to be configured with the same field type.

```
  <field name="spell" type="spellchecker" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="suggest" type="spellchecker" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <fieldType name="spellchecker" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```